# SOCKS_dante(1.4.3)_Separate processing by port number

Tags: linux, port, pam, socks, dante

I have installed dante and it is working fine. In addition, I want to divide the process according to the port number of the client, but it doesn't work.

I want to divide the processing as follows.
Access from port 3080 is PAM authentication.
Access from port 4080 does nothing.

My settings are below, how can I change them to work?
I have been working on this issue for 96 hours. It's very troubled.

```
logoutput: syslog stdout /data/socks/log/sockd.log
errorlog: /data/socks/log/sockd_err.log
debug: 1
internal: eth0 port = 3080
internal: eth0 port = 4080
external: eth2
clientmethod: none
socksmethod: pam.username
user.privileged:root
user.unprivileged:nobody

client pass {
       from: 0.0.0.0/0 port 1-4000 to: 0.0.0.0/0
       log: connect disconnect error
       socksmethod: pam
}

client pass {
       from: 0.0.0.0/0 port 4001-6000 to: 0.0.0.0/0
       log: connect disconnect error 
}

socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        command: bind connect udpassociate
        protocol: tcp udp
        log: connect disconnect error
}
```